# Android studio invalid characters

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using the android studio and am having problems with the encoding

Some characters are printing like this �

I already tried to change the encoding project and ide , but didn't work

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me, you probably are using a code on mac that was created on Windows, you make sure to save on UTF-8 or the enconding that you use, when you save, the program should detect the encoding, and show an alert.
Try to check your code in other editor